# Trouble gettings ALL followees using Instagram API

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to get all people I follow using the Instagram API. The call returns 50 users at a time and I'm paginating to store every follower. I follow 500 people but am only receiving 150 in total. What could be going wrong?

```
# returns a list of ids
def find_users_we_follow():
    ids = []
    followed_users = IGapi.user_follows(CLIENT_ID, as_generator=True)
    # IG returns 50 users at a time which we have to paginate through
    for page in followed_users:
        for user in page[0]:
            ids.append(user)
    return ids
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds crazy.. but.. try something like this:

```
def find_users_we_follow():
ids = set()
if len(ids) != 500:
   followed_users = IGapi.user_follows(CLIENT_ID, as_generator=True)
       for page in followed_users:
          for user in page[0]:
                    ids.add(user)
 else:
    return ids
```

ok why?

In my experience, their is like no logic to how instagram returns your followers with this call. Keep making the call until you get 500 unique ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the Instagram User endpoint to get number of followers and follows.

```
GET/users/user-id
```

Get basic information about a user. To get information about the owner of the access token, you can use self instead of the user-id.